# how to run socket in background in flutter (android)

Tags: android, flutter, websocket, android-workmanager

Many people has asked a same question but i did not found any relevant answer.
I have tried Work Manager and Alarm Manager plugin but these plugins gives response at every 15 min,but i want continuous response from socket when app is closed or in background, also tried in native android but it did not worked.

Thanks in advance..